# Why is not ngOnInit in Angular private?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm checking the code samples and even [the docs](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) getting nothing av information. Then, I google for a while and still nothing.

Why do we type

```
ngOnInit() { ... }
```

instead of

```
private ngOnInit() { ... }
```

or, for that matter, as long as I'm whining on the subject

```
private ngOnInit() : void { ... }
```

to embrace the full power of TypeScript?

**edit**

Based on the comments I need to extend the question. Why don't we write:

```
public ngOnInit() : void { ... }
```

instead?

Comment: what does the "full power of typescript" has to do with the visibility of that method?

Comment: Because it has to be called by the framework.

Comment: You absolutely can add `: void` to it if you want to, that is the signature (and literally is *what it says in the docs you've linked to*), but it's optional to add the void return type. It's not private because if it was private *how could Angular call it?*

Comment: @jonrsharpe Please see the edit.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo The pseudo-hard-typed variables and methods.

Comment: @Henry Please see the edit.

Comment: Same question to you, then: **yes, why don't you?** If that's what you want to write, fine. But `public` access is the default, so you don't *need* to.

Comment: public is the default, you can write it or not, it does not make a difference.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Got it. I didn't realize that it was such a broadly used convention. Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: Did you consider [reading the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#public-private-and-protected-modifiers)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the hint. I must admit I didn't scrutinize it. My bad.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The method is called from Angular.
If it were private, it couldn't be called from outside.

The returned value is ignored by Angular, therefore the return type doesn't matter.

Comment: Please see the edit. I missed that it could be `public`. Still, why don't we ever write that explictly?

Comment: `public` is the default. Writing it explicitely is redundant.

Comment: For those w/ a C# background, C# infers the least accessibility possible when this modifier is missing.  Typescript is different in that it simply defaults to public.   This makes being explicit in Typescript redundant while in C# being explicit is a best practice.

Answer (score 10):

> Based on the comments I need to extend the question. Why don't we write:
>   `public ngOnInit() : void { ... }`
>   instead?

TypeScript is able to provide contextual type information, so when you are implementing an interface, you don't need to repeat types from the interface.

For example, if you consider the following shortened example:

```
interface OnInit { 
  ngOnInit(): void
}

const example: OnInit = {
   ngOnInit: function () { }   
}
```

If you hover over `ngOnInit` you'll see the return type is *already* void, because it has inferred the return type for you contextually.

[image: Contextual Type Inference]

So in short, TypeScript wants to save you having to repeat unnecessary annotations.

## Return Type Compatibility

There is one case that might make you consider adding the return type annotation. With no annotation, the following is allowed:

```
const x: OnInit = {
    ngOnInit: function () {
        return 4;
    }   
}
```

In the specific case of the `OnInit` interface, this won't cause any problems as the return type is ignored. However, if you wanted to be told that your return type doesn't look right, the annotation would give you that additional information:

```
interface OnInit { 
  ngOnInit(): void
}

const x: OnInit = {
    ngOnInit: function (): void {
        return 4;
    }   
}
```

Like this:

[image: Return type checking]

Comment: But why is not ngOnInit in Angular private? For example i don't want to implement OnInit interface.

Comment: @yurzui - you create a component and pass it to Angular. Angular will then call the `ngOnInit` method - it acts like a hook for an event. If it were private, Angular would not be able to call it. You don't *have* to put any code in there if you don't want to.

Comment: Indeed angular calls it through `directive.ngOnInit` where directive is `any`

Comment: Angular relies on metadata that is collected from typescript AST. But even in this case angular will find that method

Comment: Based on the specific implementation in the compiler, it would find the method. This would be a fragile architecture, as if the compiler was updated (i.e. to introduce an additional closure) every Angular app would then break.